# Apex Sharing Rule - Test Class - Create sharing error?

Tags: apex, unit-test, custom-object, sharing, apex-managed-sharing

I can't quite figure out how to intentionally cause a sharing rule error for my test class. Can someone help me out?

*Reviewed Name* and *Reviewer Name* are required fields on the page layout.

**UPDATED - Final working test class shown below for others benefit!**

**Trigger:**

```
trigger PerformanceReviewApexSharing on Performance_Reviews__c (after insert) {

    if(trigger.isInsert){
        // Create a new list of sharing objects for Performance Reviews
        List<Performance_Reviews__Share> ReviewShrs  = new List<Performance_Reviews__Share>();

        // Declare variables for Reviewer and Reviewed user sharing
        Performance_Reviews__Share reviewerShr;
        Performance_Reviews__Share reviewedbyShr;

        for(Performance_Reviews__c review : trigger.new){
            // Instantiate the sharing objects
            reviewerShr = new Performance_Reviews__Share();
            reviewedbyShr = new Performance_Reviews__Share();

            // Set the ID of record being shared
            reviewerShr.ParentId = review.Id;
            reviewedbyShr.ParentId = review.Id;

            BCS__c reviewerHub = [Select ID,User__c FROM BCS__c WHERE ID = :review.Reviewer_Name__c];
            BCS__c reviewedHub = [Select ID,User__c FROM BCS__c WHERE ID = :review.Reviewed_Name__c];

            // Set the ID of user or group being granted access
            reviewerShr.UserOrGroupId = reviewerHub.User__c;
            reviewedbyShr.UserOrGroupId = reviewedHub.User__c;

            // Set the access level
            reviewerShr.AccessLevel = 'read';
            reviewedbyShr.AccessLevel = 'read';

            // Set the Apex sharing reason for reviewer and reviewed
            reviewerShr.RowCause = Schema.Performance_Reviews__Share.RowCause.Manual;
            reviewedbyShr.RowCause = Schema.Performance_Reviews__Share.RowCause.Manual;

            // Add objects to list for insert
            ReviewShrs.add(reviewerShr);
            ReviewShrs.add(reviewedbyShr);
        }

        // Insert sharing records and capture save result 
        // The false parameter allows for partial processing if multiple records are passed 
        // into the operation 
        Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(ReviewShrs,false);

        // Create counter
        Integer i=0;

        // Process the save results
        for(Database.SaveResult sr : lsr){
            if(!sr.isSuccess()){
                // Get the first save result error
                Database.Error err = sr.getErrors()[0];

                // Check if the error is related to a trivial access level
                // Access levels equal or more permissive than the object's default 
                // access level are not allowed. 
                // These sharing records are not required and thus an insert exception is 
                // acceptable. 
                if(!(err.getStatusCode() == StatusCode.FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION  
                                               &&  err.getMessage().contains('AccessLevel'))){
                    // Throw an error when the error is not related to trivial access level.
                    trigger.newMap.get(ReviewShrs[i].ParentId).
                      addError(
                       'Unable to grant sharing access due to following exception: '
                       + err.getMessage());
                }
            }
            i++;
        }   
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
    @isTest
public class test_PerformanceReviewApexSharing {

    //Created by Matt - 7/15/16

    @testSetup static void setupTestData(){

        //Create Testing Users
        User thisUser = [SELECT Id,Name FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
        System.runAs (thisUser) {
            InsertTestUsers.InsertUsers();
        }

        //Get Testing User Ids
        User uAdm = [Select Id,Name FROM User WHERE Alias = 'TSTADMIN'];
        User uMgr = [Select Id,Name FROM User WHERE Alias = 'TSTMGR'];
        User uBCS = [Select Id,Name FROM User WHERE Alias = 'TSTBCS'];

        //Create Hubs
        List<BCS__c> theHub = new List<BCS__c>();
        theHub.add(new BCS__c(
            Name            = thisUser.Name,
            DOH__c          = Date.today().addMonths(-24),
            User__c         = thisUser.Id,
            Admin__c        = TRUE,
            OwnerId         = thisUser.Id,
            Manager__c      = uMgr.Id,
            Supervisor__c   = uMgr.Id   
        ));
        theHub.add(new BCS__c(
            Name            = uBCS.Name,
            DOH__c          = Date.today().addMonths(-24),
            User__c         = uBCS.Id,
            Admin__c        = TRUE,
            OwnerId         = uBCS.Id,
            Manager__c      = uMgr.Id,
            Supervisor__c   = uMgr.Id   
        ));
        theHub.add(new BCS__c(
            Name            = uAdm.Name,
            DOH__c          = Date.today().addMonths(-24),
            User__c         = uAdm.Id,
            OwnerId         = uAdm.Id,
            Manager__c      = uMgr.Id,
            Supervisor__c   = uMgr.Id
        ));
        theHub.add(new BCS__c(
            Name            = uMgr.Name,
            DOH__c          = Date.today().addMonths(-24),
            User__c         = uMgr.Id,
            OwnerId         = uMgr.Id,
            Manager__c      = thisUser.Id,
            Supervisor__c   = thisUser.Id
        ));

        insert theHub;

    }


    //Create Performance Review
    @isTest static void testPerformanceReview(){
        //Get BCS Hub
        User    uBCS    = [Select Id,Name FROM User WHERE Alias = 'TSTBCS'];
        BCS__c  BCSHub  = [Select Id FROM BCS__c WHERE User__c = :uBCS.Id];
        //Get Manager Hub
        User    uMGR    = [Select Id,Name FROM User WHERE Alias = 'TSTMGR'];
        BCS__c  MGRHub  = [Select Id FROM BCS__c WHERE User__c = :uMGR.Id];
        //Get Current User Hub
        BCS__c UserHub  = [Select ID FROM BCS__c WHERE User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

        test.startTest();

        List<Performance_Reviews__c> reviews = new List<Performance_Reviews__c>();
        reviews.add(new Performance_Reviews__c(
            Name                = 'Test Review',
            Reviewed_Name__c    = BCSHub.Id,
            Reviewer_Name__c    = MGRHub.Id 
        ));
        reviews.add(new Performance_Reviews__c(
            Name                = 'Test Review - Bad Record Test',
            Reviewed_Name__c    = BCSHub.Id,
            Reviewer_Name__c    = UserHub.Id,
            OwnerId             = UserInfo.getUserId()
        ));

        Insert reviews;

        test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you just blacklist `StatusCode.FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION`, so you don't need to create an error with a specific `StatusCode`, you just need to avoid that one to get inside your `if` condition.

Attempting to insert any object where `OwnerId = UserInfo.getProfileId()` will cause an error with status code `FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION`, so that should work for you here. Also, note that there is an `Id.addError` method that you can use instead of `SObject.addError`, simplifying your logic a bit.

**Data Creation**

Replace:

```
reviews.add(new Performance_Reviews__c(
    /*data*/
));
```

with:

```
reviews.add(new Performance_Reviews__c(
    OwnerId = UserInfo.getProfileId(),
    /*data*/
));
```

**Adding Error**

Replace:

```
trigger.newMap.get(ReviewShrs[i].ParentId).addError('message');
```

with:

```
ReviewShrs[i].ParentId.addError('message');
```

Comment: Thanks @Adrain, the trigger code is from the Salesforce example. I just tweaked it to meet my needs.

Comment: @Matt not sure what you're getting at, did my answer not help you?

Comment: sorry, i was just commenting on your suggested code changes. I bet your solution will work. Just haven't tried it yet. Will mark best answer once I do.

Comment: you have one small mistype. You told me to use  OwnerId = UserInfo.getProfileId() when it should be OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId().

Comment: That would not cause an error, and hence not get you into the `if` block. It's written that way on purpose.